# Urn probability function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose I have an urn with an infinite number of balls which can be either red or white. I do not know what the proportion of each colour is, but I *do* know it's a fixed proportion. After drawing $N$ balls, I have observed $r$ red ones and $w$ white ones.

I believe the probability that I will observe a red ball on the next draw is given by Laplace's Law of Succession, $\frac{r+1}{N+2}$. However, how sure should I be of that? That is, before I drew any balls, I believed any proportion other than $0$ or $1$ was the true one. After I drew those $N$ balls, what should be my estimated pdf over the possible values for the proportion of red balls in the urn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, my first idea was using Jaynes' $A_p$ distribution, in which case we can define $A$ = next draw will be red and $N_r$ = out of $N$ draws, $r$ were red. With an ignorant prior distribution $(A_p|X) = 1$, I get that

$$(A_p|N_rX) = (A_p|X)\frac{P(N_r|A_p)}{P(N_r|X)}$$

We know that

$$P(N_r|A_p) = \binom{N}{r}p^r(1-p)^{N-r}$$

And we can find

$$P(N_r|X) = \int^1_0(N_rA_p|X)dp = \int^1_0P(N_r|A_p)(A_p|X)dp = \int^1_0\binom{N}{r}p^r(1-p)^{N-r}dp$$

from which

$$P(N_r|X) = \frac 1 {N+1}, 0 \leq r \leq N$$

And then

$$(A_p|N_r) = (N+1)\binom{N}{r}p^r(1-p)^{N-r}$$

And that looks like my distribution. Is that correct?

Comment: You seem to think your uninformed prior is uniform. If so, you obtain the result you have, though there are easier ways. But Jaynes' hero Sir Harold Jeffreys would have suggested a less moderate Beta prior, and in fact there is not real justiification for a Beta prior except mathematical convenience.

Comment: What are these easier ways? Also, what would be this less moderate Beta prior, given that before drawing the balls from the urn I know nothing except that red and white balls are possible in a fixed proportion?

Comment: Easy: If your prior distribution is proportional to $p^{\alpha-1} (1-p)^{\beta-1}$ and the likelihood of the observation is proportional to $p^{r} (1-p)^{N-r}$ then by multiplication the posterior distribution is proportional to $p^{\alpha+r-1} (1-p)^{\beta+N-r-1}$, i.e. is a $B(\alpha+r, \beta+N-r)$ distribution.

Comment: Your prior is a $Beta(1,1)$ distribution.  A $B(\frac12,\frac12)$ [Jeffrey's prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior) would be less moderate, and an improper Haldane $B(0,0)$ prior even less moderate.  In 1968 Jaynes preferred the last of these.